# How to remove all special characters in column names by regex but stay ":" in re in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have Pandas DataFrame in Python like below:

```
COL1   | XX:\x84Â\x82Ă\x82Â\  | \x84Â\x82Ă\PPx82Â\
-------|----------------------|--------------------
111    | ABC                  | X
222    | CCC                  | Y
333    | DDD                  | XX

My code and current output:
```

By using below code I am able to delete any special characters from columns names and return list of columns with converted names. But I also replace ":" to "_"

```
import re

new_names = {col: re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9_]+', '', col) for col in df.columns}
new_n_list = list(new_names.values())

[COL1, XX_A, PP]
```

**My question:**

How can I modify my code, so as to work as now but do not convert ":" to "_"

**Desire output:**

```
   [COL1, XX:A, PP]
```

Comment: Where is the A in XX_A coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this regex?

```
new_names = {col: re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9_]|(?<!:):(?!:)', '', col) for col in df.columns}
```